# Why add a constraint in one to many relationship entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, constraints

I'm trying to understand the difference in my one-to-many relationship after I add a virtual call back to my main entity 'space'. All it does, looking at the tables is create a constraint. Can someone please explain the difference between having

> public virtual Space Space { get; set; }

and leaving it out?

Here is my main entity 'space' and 'spaceimage' that has the virtual call back to 'space'

```
public class Space
{
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SpaceImage> Images { get; set; }  
}

public class SpaceImage
{
    public int SpaceImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageThumbnail { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }

    public virtual Space Space { get; set; } // adds a constraint in sql server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the difference is you can make a call like this :

```
  var thisSpace = _context.Space.Include( x => x.Images).Where( blah == blah);
```

ok, so know you got your space from the database , now you don't need any other query at all to get images, you would just do.

```
  thisSpace.Images // now this is filled with a collection of images
```

You do not need a join , you don't need to do anything at all - see how awesome Entity Framework is.  The down side... is the is some overhead in a framework that  can do stuff like this.

UPDATE:

you asked about Lazy Loading , you still have control of lazy loading or not.

See if you were to  do :

```
   var thisSpace = _context.Space.Include( x => x.Images).Where( blah == blah).ToList();
```

then the query will execute right away and the Images will be attached. or..

you could do something like

```
   var thisSpace = _context.Space.Include( x => x.Images).Where( blah == blah);
   foreach( var image in thisSpace.Images){
   // when you hit this in code the query will actually execute
   // if lazy loading
   }
```

Comment: hi Scott. If I have other entities inside my 'space' entity, ex. address, would I also be able to pull the address out in the same query? In your example you have just x => x.Images, but what if I wanted addresses, receipts, etc?

Comment: one more question. this would still be lazy loading the images right?

Comment: is that a no to lazy loading or a no to not being able to put more then images in the query?

Comment: I meant you still control Lazy loading - having relationships defined in the data objects has nothing to do with weather you are implementing lazy loading